# Australia 600 Visitor visa, Can I reapply while the existing visa is still active?

Tags: visas, australia

I had applied for visitor visa for my in-laws. It expires in Oct. Unfortunately they cannot visit Australia until after Oct.

I was wondering if they can apply for new visitor visa while the existing Visitor (subclass 600) visa is still active (until Oct)?

PS: Note sure if it matters but I had applied it online using online.immi.gov.au website and plan to apply for the same visa using the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they can apply for a new Visitor (subclass 600) visa at any time.

Note that under [subsection 82(2)](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2019C00181/Html/Volume_1#_Toc8205811) of the *Migration Act 1959*, if the new visa application is approved it will immediately replace the old visa.

Comment: IIUC condition 8503 (No further stay) on a current visa would disallow this. https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/see-your-visa-conditions?product=600-29A#

Comment: @jcm 8503 only bans visa applications while the person is in Australia.  It does not prevent applying for a new visa if the person is outside Australia, like the OP.

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for clearing that up.